# Error importing 'react-redux' and 'redux', while running react-native app using snack.expo.io website in PC and expo app in android

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

I was trying to make a **react-native app** with **redux**, which is a **counter**. I was using [snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/) website in PC and **expo app** in Android, as I can't run it plainly in my system due to limitations .The app runs but when i click any of the buttons, it shows the error:

**" Failed to install module 'react-redux': 

Attempted to import missing module 'redux' 

imported from App.js"**

[The snack.expo.io page i made is given here](https://snack.expo.io/B1eqJ1OKM)

I did add the **'redux'** and **'react-redux'** into the **package.json** file. Still it shows the same error.

What did I do wrong, or is there any other way to use 'redux' and 'react-redux' in expo?

I saw the same app being run on a system using npm and all. So I suspect it is a problem with snack.expo.io, as the import for the libraries mentioned are not working.

Do look through the code and let me know what I can do.

**Update:**

The documentation in which all modules available in snack contains 'redux' and 'react-redux' as shown in the answer by Tetsuya3850.

https://forums.expo.io/t/modules-available-in-snack/1651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snack is constantly changing and right now and it seems to be throwing the wrong error. I downloaded your snack and ran it with `exp` [the expo command line tool](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/exp-cli.html#content). This revealed a few syntax errors which can be simply resolved!

- `counterActions.AddNumber -> counterActions.addNumber`
- `counterActions.DecrementCount -> counterActions.decrementCount`
- There is also another error related to formatting: `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

I'll share this with TC the dev working on snack, he's pretty good at 
fixing these kinds of problems.

---

**A lazy man's opinion of Redux**

It looks like you are running into some of the usual errors of standard Redux.
Standard Redux gives me chest pain  - I highly recommend using **[Rematch](https://github.com/rematch/rematch)**!

- Rematch is a standard format for Redux, you may have noticed that 
  everyone formats a little different.
- A lot less code and much easier to manage. Because of how it's structured you tend to use more shallow redux objects which can really help performance.
- Async is built in... so yeah
- Here is a counter example using rematch  https://snack.expo.io/@bacon/rematch-example notice how little code is used, there are also more features in this example than in the snack provided above.
- It can be weird incorporating with `react-navigation` but Brent Vatne the dev currently working on react-navigation says you should avoid using redux with it anyways. ‍♀️
- I am **not affiliated** with Rematch even though this seems like a very bias review.

Comment: Concur on using Rematch.  I am a minor contributor to the project.  It greatly simplifies redux.

Answer (score 0):

I think the packages that you could use in snack are limited. (https://forums.expo.io/t/modules-available-in-snack/1651)

But the limitation is changing real-time?
(https://forums.expo.io/t/adding-new-modules-to-expo-snack/1496/4)

Comment: 'redux' and 'react-redux' are shown in 'modules available in snack'. Now that is what I don't get. At first when I save the snack, it will show 'no errors' and when I scan the QR code, the app is shown, but when I click on the button( where the libraries come to matter ) , It shows the error as I described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For thouse who came here with this same problem, you can manually add it to the dependency list.

Go to package.json, at dependencies use the following format
"package": "version", you may want to chack the currently version of you package
ie:

```
"dependencies":{
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "react-redux": "7.2.1",
}
```

You may have other dependencies before or after.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oft4R.png)